# Javascript - Find multiple values in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, multidimensional-array

Got some JSON that I need to go through to fetch some IDs.
The JSON looks like this:

```
var carousel = [
  {
    "acf": {
      "content": [
        {
          "acf_fc_layout": "custom",
          "content": "Some text"
        },
        {
          "acf_fc_layout": "exhibition",
          "exhibition": 2594
        },
        {
          "acf_fc_layout": "exhibition",
          "exhibition": 1234
        }
      ]
    },
  }
]
```

For every `content` where `acf_fc_layout == exhibition` I must fetch the value (ID) of exhibition so it can be used to fetch further data. As you can see there's multiple exhibition IDs aswell.

My confusion here is that there are both object and array, and that they're nested. I've done some similar stuff with jQuery, but that's out of the question this time. Don't think I need IE8 support, but still find this tricky..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON simply looks as you say, this is a simple solution:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < carousel[0].acf.content.length; i++) {
    if (carousel[0].acf.content[i].acf_fc_layout === "exhibition") {
        // do something with carousel[0].acf.content[i].exhibition
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you have much more content in your JSON, this might be relevant:

```
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < carousel.length; i++) {
    if (typeof carousel[i].acf != 'undefined' && typeof carousel[i].acf.content != 'undefined') {
        for (j = 0; j < carousel[i].acf.content.length; j++) {
            if (carousel[i].acf.content[j].acf_fc_layout === "exhibition") {
                // do something with carousel[i].acf.content[j].exhibition
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second solution? Why is that better if I have more content?

Comment: That will run through all of the data in your JSON, so if you have multiple elements in carousel (the top level list) matching the format of the one element (carousel[i].acf.content[j].acf_fc_layout), the second solution will allow for you to access those other elements' exhibition id.

Comment: Browser compatibility? I only use basic JavaScript constructs, so as far as I'm aware, it should run on anything that supports JavaScript. I'm no JavaScript expert, but I would be shocked if you could find a browser that supports JavaScript, but not that code.

Answer (score 1):

```
carousel[0].acf.content.forEach(function (item) {
  if (item["acf_fc_layout"] === "exhibition") {
    // do some stuff
    // id for exhibition placed in item["exhibition"] 
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah, simple enough. Works in IE9> I suppose?

Comment: Both [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [caniuse](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.forEach) say yes, `forEach` works starting in IE9.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < carousel[0].acf.content.length; i++) {
  var item = carousel[0].acf.content[i];
  if (item["acf_fc_layout"] === "exhibition") {
    // do some stuff
  }
}

This should work in IE8

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/oucp3v5x/

```
$(carousel).each(function(i, el){

    $(el.acf.content).each(function(i, el){
        if(el.acf_fc_layout === 'exhibition') {
            $('<div>', {
                text: el.exhibition
            }).appendTo($('#results'));
        }
    });

});
```

If `acf` have many `content`, you need to run additional loop and acf have to be array of objects.

Comment: `acf` is an associative array. Associative arrays can't have multiple keys of the same name, so it can't have "many `content`".

Comment: "and acf have to be array of objects." the key word of my comment. It's a tip.

Answer (score 0):

With your current structure, you need to use a foreach and check the value.

```
 var carousel = [
  {
    "acf": {
      "content": [
        {
          "acf_fc_layout": "custom",
          "content": "Some text"
        },
        {
          "acf_fc_layout": "exhibition",
          "exhibition": 2594
        },
        {
          "acf_fc_layout": "exhibition",
          "exhibition": 1234
        }
      ]
    },
  }
];

$.each(carousel[0].acf.content,function (i,v){
    if(v.acf_fc_layout == "exhibition")
        $(".result").append(v.exhibition+"<br>");
    });
```

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1d9v3zug/1/)